# Animating effect properties that are inside other effects using Windows.UI.Composition

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I'm currently trying to animate Lights, that are inside the Source property of a CompositeEffect inside a BlendEffect using Windows.UI.Composition. This is my code:

```
       var graphicsEffect = new BlendEffect
        {
            Mode = BlendEffectMode.Multiply,
            Background = new CompositeEffect()
            {
                Name = "comp",
                Mode = Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasComposite.Add,
                Sources =
                {
                    new PointDiffuseEffect()
                    {
                        Name = "Light1",
                        DiffuseAmount = 1f,
                    },
                    new PointDiffuseEffect()
                    {
                        Name = "Light2",
                        DiffuseAmount = 1f,
                    },
                },
            },

            Foreground = new GaussianBlurEffect()
            {
                Name = "Blur",
                Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("Backdrop"),
                BlurAmount = 12f,
                BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
            }
        };
```

The issue is that when I try to animate the position or color of those lights, I'm told that "Animate property refers to an effect not in the graph". Is this even possible? If not, what kind of workaround would there be? I've tried calling `Light1.Lightposition`, `comp.Light1.Lightposition`, and `comp.Sources.Light1.Lightposition`, but none of those work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your reply in your MSDN thread:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/65a1f1a0-8c8c-414e-9734-ec5f407b3c6e/uwpanimating-effect-properties-that-are-inside-other-effects-using-windowsuicomposition?forum=wpdevelop.

Thanks.